# How can I validate uniqueness of two columns in Laravel 4?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, php-5.3

How can I validate uniqueness of two columns in Laravel 4?

Suppose, `first_name` and `last_name` are two columns. I want to check `first_name last_name` will be unique.

Answer (score 7):

There is a community developed package for that: https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator.

1. Install it through Composer. In your composer.json file add: `"felixkiss/uniquewith-validator": "dev-master"` in the require property.
2. Add the validator as a provider in the config/app.php file: `'Felixkiss\UniqueWithValidator\UniqueWithValidatorServiceProvider'`
3. Finally use it as follow:

   ```php
   $rules = array(
       'first_name' => 'unique_with:users,last_name',
   );
   ```

Check the [package page](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator).

Comment: Isn't is possible to apply unique validation for multiple columns without using this package "uniquewith-validator"? I am simply expecting a syntax to write a rule for unique validation in the model like 'label'=>'required|unique:sections,label,'.$this->event_id.',event_id  but it is giving me an syntax error. How can i pass posted event id in this validation so that it could check whether any label exists with selected event id in the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom Validatior,

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules

```
Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
   /*
            check whether "first_name + last_name" is unique with SQL. Pass them as  parameters 
   */
});
```